# how to ignore a regex result in a string

Tags: regex

I want to find matched regex in a string and then ignore this matches, then work with remain parts of string. For example my pattern is :

```
alt=('|").*('|")
```

and my string is :

```
<div class='divClass'><img src='image.png' alt="abcdef"></div>
```

I want to get this string finaly :

```
<div class='divClass'><img src='image.png'></div>
```

note: the value of alt attribute changes dynamically.

Comment: which flavor? JS? PHP?

Comment: I want to parse HTML codes by java web in server.

Comment: Java web...? Sure it's not JS?

Comment: I want to build HTMLcode in server and put them in response then send this response to a client. My server side language is java and work with servlets. But before putting HTML code in response I want to change some parts. So you answer me in PHP please. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need php:

```
$re = "/\\s*alt=([\"']).*?\\1/"; 
$str = "<div class='divClass'><img src='image.png' alt=\"abcdef\"></div>"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Comment: Is there any way to find rest of string with regex? I mean find a regex that do this Instead of writing PHP code? or how to negate this pattern?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your need @AtefehRashidi

Comment: OK. No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex pattern:

```
(<img[^>]*?) alt=(['"]).*?\2([^>]*?>)
```

It will return the string you want (everything but the `alt="..."` part) in the first and third result group, you only have to concatenate them.

This is easily done using the String's `replaceAll(pattern, replacement)` method and the group placeholders `"$n"` in the replacement string:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(<img[^>]*?) alt=([\'\"]).*?\2([^>]*?>)", "$1$3");
```

Note that you need to escape the type of quotes inside the regex which you use to enclose the String literal in your Java code - or simply both.

---

Pattern explanation:

```
  Group 1    part to remove   Group 3
|----------||---------------||-------|
(<img[^>]*?) alt=(['\"]).*?\2([^>]*?>)
     \____/      \_____/   \/ \____/
       1.          2.      3.   1.
```

1. `[^>]*?` matches the shortest possible string that does not contain any `>` characters that would terminate the img tag.
2. `(['\"])` matches either a single or a double quote. The double quote is escaped so that it can be used as String literal delimiter in Java. It is enclosed in a group so that we can later match the exact closing quote.
3. `\2` matches the previously matched quote character that correctly terminates the string attribute value.

Comment: FYI: `\2` inside a `[^\2]` is treated as an escape sequence, not a backreference.

Comment: @Thomas @ Wiktor I fixed my pattern. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: `(<img.*?) alt=(['"]).*?\2(.*?>)` does the same :)

Comment: @Thomas But that would also match a false-positive like this: `<img src='image.png'><blub alt="abcdef">`

Comment: You're right. `(<img[^>]*?) alt=(['"]).*?\2(.*?>)` won't.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, after thinking about it again, the text inside quotes can probably really be simplified using `.*?` without side-effects.